# delete 1st row in ValueListEditor, if RowCount>1, delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

```
RowCount=4;
```

delete 1st row in ValueListEditor, if RowCount>1, in delphi

delete must fixed row but, please: correct code for delete Rows?

```
    procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
       DelR: Integer;
    begin

         if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count <1 ) then Exit;

       ShowMessage( ' DeleteRow № '+ IntToStr( ValueListEditor1.Row)+sLineBreak+
                    ' ValueListEditor1.RowCount = '+ IntToStr(ValueListEditor1.RowCount)+sLineBreak+
                    ' ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count = '+ IntToStr( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count));

       DelR:= ValueListEditor1.Row;


          if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count=1 ) or
             ( DelR=1 ) then
          begin
             ShowMessage(' 1 ');

             if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count=1 ) then
                  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Clear
             else
                  ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(DelR);

//            if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count>1 ) then
//            begin
//               ValueListEditor1.Row:= DelR +1;
//               ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(DelR);
//               ValueListEditor1.SetFocus;
//               Exit;
//            end;



Exit;
  end
  else
     if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count>1 ) or
        ( DelR = ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count-1) then
     begin
        ShowMessage(' 2 ');

        ValueListEditor1.Row:= DelR -1;  // !!! ValueListEditor1.Row -1 = DelR
        ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(ValueListEditor1.Row);
        ValueListEditor1.SetFocus;
        Exit;
     end;

//         else
//          if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count=1 )then
//               ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(ValueListEditor1.Row)
//          else
//               ValueListEditor1.Row:= PreviuRow +1;


//      if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count>1 ) and not
//         ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count=1 ) then
//           ValueListEditor1.Row:= PreviuRow -1
//      else
//          if ( ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count=1 )then
//               ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(ValueListEditor1.Row)
//          else
//               ValueListEditor1.Row:= PreviuRow +1;

//      ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(ValueListEditor1.Row);

// !!!??? NOT  ->  ValueListEditor1.DeleteRow(ValueListEditor1.Row);


//   if ValueListEditor1.Row=ValueListEditor1.RowCount  then
//   begin
//        ValueListEditor1.DeleteRow(ValueListEditor1.Row);
//        ValueListEditor1.Row:= PreviuRow;
//
//   end
///   else ValueListEditor1.DeleteRow(ValueListEditor1.Row);


end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be one strange component.. Please test if the below does what you want:

```
if ValueListEditor1.Row - Ord(doColumnTitles in ValueListEditor1.DisplayOptions)
    < ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count then begin
  if (ValueListEditor1.Row = 0) then
    ValueListEditor1.Strings.Delete(0)
  else
    ValueListEditor1.DeleteRow(ValueListEditor1.Row);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but                                                                  if   ValueListEditor1.Row = ValueListEditor1.Strings.Count,             Error: "List index of bounbs (3)" .

Comment: @Dima - I can't seem to duplicate that. You have 1 title row, 3 additional rows and you're deleting the last one, is this correct?

Comment: Sample list 1-Title row & 4 Data rows

Comment: Now 1st row with Data rows goot delete, thank You. But, if delete 4th row with Data rows - error: "List index of bounbs (3)" ???

Comment: @Dima - I can't duplicate, sorry. I'm selecting the 4th data row and then clicking on a button with the above handler, and it deletes the row fine here. All it should be doing is `ValueListEditor1.DeleteRow(4)` since `ValueListEditor1.Row` is '4'.

Comment: Yea, Your truth, in Vcl.ValEdit.pas is Reef: spy 1st row. `ValueListEditor1.InsertRow('', '', True );` -delete it reef. `ValueListEditor1.Strings.Append( '' +'='+ '' );` -not delete it reef. `ValueListEditor1.Strings.Add( '' +'='+ '' );` -not delete it reef. What i do: `procedure TOpenPL_F.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ValueListEditor1.Strings.Clear;
end;` // All good work.

Comment: **Thank You, All good work.**